# Eclipse autocompletion like intellisense

Tags: java, eclipse, intellisense

MS Visual Studio's autocompletion is called intellisense and the code completion doesn't list the possible functions etc in alphebetical order. It looks at the code around where you are typing and puts the most likely function etc at the top. For instance, if you have called a function named "Draw" multiple times previously, it will move "Draw" up in the list. Eclipse code completion just lists the functions etc in alphebetical order. The attached image shows what I mean. Is there any way of getting the code completion to act like Intellisense?

[image: Eclipse]

Comment: What version of Eclipse do you have? I'm pretty sure the newest release does this

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install [Eclipse Recommenders Plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/). It uses information collected from other developers and tries to provide you most relevant completion.

> Code Recommenders automatically analyzes existing code using that API and extracts common usage rules and patterns from it. In the form of recommendation models, this knowledge is then fed back into your IDE. Code Recommenders’ intelligent code completion and extended API documentation then utilizes the power of these models to provide you with the solutions implemented by other developers in the past.

Comment: I don't want solutions from other developers. I want eclipse to look at my code and suggest what would be useful instead of just having it in alphabetical order.

Comment: so basically, the image shows how I am using glVector2i multiple times and yet eclipse code recommender still puts it behind glVector2d and glVector2f.